# Javascript passing numbers by reference issue with simple recursive function

Tags: javascript

I've built this simple recursive function.

The recursion is easily visible as it should draw a tree like nested pattern of boxes. The boxes are also shifted downwards slightly each iteration to make it clearer where there are overlapping lines.

```
    ___________
1. |           |
   |           |
   |           |
   |           |
   |           |
   |___________|

    ___________
2. |___________|
   |     |     |
   |     |     |
   |     |     |
   |     |     |
   |_____|_____|
   |_____|_____|

    __ __ __ __
3. |___________|
   |_____|_____|
   |  |  |  |  |
   |  |  |  |  |
   |  |  |  |  |
   |__|__|__|__|
   |__|__|__|__|
   |__|__|__|__|
```

http://codepen.io/alan2here/pen/reFwo

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

box(50, 50, 150, 150);

function box(x, y, width, height) {
  // draw the box
    line(x, y, x + width, y);
    line(x, y, x, y + height);
    line(x, y + height, x + width, y + height);
    line(x + width, y, x + width, y + height);

  // continue with a tree like nested pattern of sub-boxes inside this one.
    if (width > 100) {
      width2 = width * 0.5;
      box(x, y + 5, width2, height);
      box(x + width2, y + 5, width2, height);
    }
}

function line(x, y, x2, y2) {
  canvas.beginPath();
  canvas.moveTo(x, y);
  canvas.lineTo(x2, y2);
  canvas.closePath();
  canvas.stroke();
}
```

However, this abruptly stops working at iteration 3, as can be seen if `width > 100` is changed to `width > 50`.

```
    __ __ __ __
3. |_____      |
   |__|__|     |
   |  |  |     |
   |  |  |     |
   |  |  |     |
   |__|__|_____|
   |__|__|
   |__|__|
```

It seems as if values may be getting passed by reference where they shouldn't be, however I thought numbers in JS passed by copying the value, and what's more I'm creating most of the passed values from scratch, for example `..., x + width, ...` and `width2 = width * 0.5`.

Why is the program not working.

---

Thanks Benni for the slight correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are always passed by value in Javascript. It doesn't even support passing parameter by reference.

The problem is that you are using a global variable:

```
width2 = width * 0.5;
```

When you make the first recursive call it will change the value of the global variable, so the second recursive call will use the value from the last iteration instead.

Declare the variable in the function so that it is local:

```
var width2 = width * 0.5;
```

Comment: whoah, by default not declaring in the scope your in? Thank you very much. Static like this is a potentially powerful, but I'm sure it would have been better to need a term like 'var' for global definition, not for local.

Comment: @alan2here Welcome to Javascript! :D

Answer (score 1):

First guess: change your code to

```
 if (width > 100) {
  var width2 = width * 0.5;
  box(x, y + 5, width2, height);
  box(x + width2, y + 5, width2 , height);
}
```

Comment: It seems strange that should make any difference although it does, slightly, the code is also slightly neater now and should have been that anyway, although still not working.

Comment: local variables are needed here. Notice the Change in the 2nd box() call, too